# Smooth Verts Tool

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

I know you can do something like this in sculpt mode with the smooth brush, but what about in edit mode?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything which looks quite like your gif, but there is the *Smooth Vertices* operator, accessible via <kbd>W</kbd>*> Smooth* or *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd>)*> Tools > Mesh Tools > Deform > Smooth Vertex*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically smooth the mesh as in the example, you can use the smooth sculpt brush. There is no reason you can't go into sculpt mode and smooth out a portion of the mesh before going back to edit mode.

In edit mode you can smooth the selected vertices either with [smooth or laplacian smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/smooth.html) - both can be found in the specials menu <kbd>W</kbd>.

With laplacian smooth, the defaulteffect is subtle, you probably won't see a change when you do it. You should do it and then adjust the operator options to see a change, either press <kbd>F6</kbd> or look at the bottom of the toolbar.